# django/gunicorn app restart

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have 2 different projects running on the same server. They are both Django projects with Gunicorn as wsgi server. The server on top is Apache. Currently there is a Jenkins job that updates the source code from the repo and restart(Kill and start) gunicorn. This worked fine till the server was only serving 1 site. 
I killed the gunicorn as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs  kill -9
```

and then restarted it. However this approach will will not work with 2 sites, since killing Gunicorn completely kills all Gunicorn processes. At any time I run the build, only the gunicorn for that that site will get re spawned.

I looked around and i found that Supervisor was one utility that I should use to prevent this and seamlessly restart Gunicorn.

Do you guys have have other suggestions or best practices that I should follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only grab your project's gunicorn and restart it, you can use the following:

```
ps aux |grep gunicorn |grep yourappname | awk '{ print $2 }' |xargs kill -HUP
```

Other gunicorn processes will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn + Supervisor is pretty standard stack, you could have your sites separated as different Supervisor tasks and instead of telling Jenkins to restart Supervisor, use the Supervisor method for restarting just one of your tasks, and you're done.

Supervisor is also great if your site crashes and Gunicorn needs to be executed again.

Comment: Thanks for the response.